# vue-cal 3.9 works and vue-cal 3.11 has an issue with drag-and-drop.js not existing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cal

I have a vue project and I'm using vue-cal 3.9 with no issues.

When I `ls node_modules/vue-cal/dist` I have `drag-and-drop.js`

When I upgrade to vue-cal 3.11, I have the following in `node_modules/vue-cal/dist` (note there is not a drag-and-drop.js):

```
drag-and-drop.amd.js    drag-and-drop.es.js     vue-cal.amd.js          vue-cal.es.js           vuecal.css
drag-and-drop.cjs.js    i18n                    vue-cal.cjs.js          vue-cal.iife.js
```

When I build, I get this error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* vue-cal/dist/drag-and-drop.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/events/Calendar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

Any idea why 1) vue-cal does not have a vanilla drag-and-drop.js in the new version and 2) how can I use the new version?

Editing to add github issue link https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal/issues/517

Comment: I would say this has to do with rollup or vite, at first glance. I think the common js file (cjs) is what you want. I've had some issues with this with other libraries in the past, and it's just a trial and error approach, imo.

Comment: Trial and error? You mean trying different versions of the library, or what? I'm using webpack...

Comment: I mean importing one-or-the-other of the files found in the module. See which  one might work, if any.

Answer (score 1):

The drag and drop file is automatically lazy-loaded since version 3.11.0.

Here are 2 working demos of Vue Cal with drag & drop:

- running on Vue Cal 3.10.4: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuecal-vue2-7jjee8?file=src%2FApp.vue
- running on Vue Cal 3.11.0: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuecal-vue2-uzsas3?file=src%2FApp.vue,package.json

For more details, check my answer @ https://github.com/antoniandre/vue-cal/issues/517